# Get the Async value of an Angular Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

***getPropertiesByStatusService.js*** (service)

```
(function () {
    appModule.service('getPropertiesByStatusService', ['abp.services.app.property', function (propertyService) {
        this.propertyList = function (filter) {
            propertyService.getPropertiesByStatus({ filter: filter })
                .success(function (result) {
                    return result;
                });
        };
    }
    ]);
})();
```

***index.js***(controller)

```
(function () {
    appModule.controller('tenant.views.propertymanagement.index', ['$scope',  'getPropertiesByStatusService', function ($scope, getPropertiesByStatusService) {

            var vm = this;
            var list = getPropertiesByStatusService.propertyList(null);

        }]);
})();
```

Can you tell me how to get the value for the `list` ? Due to `async` nature it doesn't show any value.

Comment: You can add `getPropertiesByStatusService.propertyList` to the resolve of route. Do you want me to explain better in answer?

Comment: Nothing is returned from `this.propertyList()`. Can't return anything inside `success`, there is nowhere to return it to. Return the promise and use `then()` in controller

Comment: @charlietfl can you explain it bit more using my code snippets ?

Comment: @Max why do I need to use route here ?

Comment: @Sampath Because it is impossible to get async data synchronously. There 2 ways: user .then() or use resolves (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

Comment: @Max OK,can you tell me how to use `then` with my scenario ?

Comment: `return propertyService.getPropertiesByStatus({ filter: filter })` ....  `getPropertiesByStatusService.propertyList(null).then(function(result){ vm.list=result; })`. This is standard use of promises

Comment: @charlietfl OK,but I cannot access `list` within my `service`.That is a `grid` data which is on my `controller` (`vm.propertyListGridOptions.data`).So then how can I do that ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking there. Not enough shown in question to sort it out. See you are in Columbo. I stayed in Negumbo for many months years ago during period of Tamil wars. Good memories of Sri Lanka

Comment: @charlietfl Aha... Nice to meet you then (not a promise then :D).Thanks man I have found out the solution.Have a nice day ! :)